# Filter data in R based on condition?

Tags: r

I want to filter the dataframe below, to where only certain rows are kept.

`total.Date` = date of event

`total.start` = start time of event

`total.TotalTime` = duration of event (minutes)

`total.ISSUE_DATE` = date of item ordered

`total.ISSUE_TIME` = time of item ordered

In this specific subsetted dataset, I believe all rows will be excluded. However when I perform this on the entire dataset, some rows are expected to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pasting together the surgery and order dates and times to form proper datetimes, then converting the integer minutes into a "period" object in `lubridate` terminology.

Then it's straightforward to filter: greater than the start time minus 30 minutes AND less than the start time plus the length of the surgery.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

your_df %>%
  mutate(
    surgery_start = mdy_hms(paste(total.Date, total.PTIN)),
    order_time = mdy_hms(paste(total.ISSUE_DATE, total.ISSUE_TIME)),
    surgery_duration = minutes(total.TotalORTime)
    ) %>%
  filter(
    order_time > surgery_start - minutes(30),
    order_time < surgery_start + surgery_duration
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Quick question, would I get the same results if I use the AND or OR operator for  the filter function? I notice that I do

Comment: With the example data you have, I think you get the same results. Using `dplyr::filter()` puts an implicit AND for every argument you give it.